# Is it legal to throw small objects (eg. candy, paper clips) at someone

Tags: criminal-law, assault, harassment, stalking

Is it legal to throw mall objects (eg. candy, paper clips)  at someone periodically throughout the day for multiple weeks. I know this may strange, but I follow this person around and throw small items at him when he is outside on a jog, when he is at the grocery store, when he is driving to work, etc. He gets really annoyed and sometimes chases me but I have avoided him and the police so far. I was wondering if I could be prosecuted for harassment or any other crime. Additionally, if what I'm doing is illegal, is there any way to do it legally? Thank you!

Comment: Stalking, assault, harrassment... You want advice on how to *persecute* someone legally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop doing this. It is definitely unethical and almost certainly illegal. There is no ethical or legal way to intentionally harass someone.

Comment: Ok thank you! Are you sure there are no ways to legally do this? What if I decrease the frequency of which I throw objects at him? Maybe once every few days? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @duncan_evelyn throwing the items is probably [battery](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/battery). It is probably offensive contact, because it would make a "reasonable person of ordinary sensibilities feel threatened." I don't know what jurisdiction you're in, but in Oregon, this would also be [harassment](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_166.065) under ORS 166.065; I expect that it would be harassment in most if not all jurisdictions. At least in Oregon, harassment does not have to be persistent; the first time you did this was likely battery and harassment, as well as each time since.

Comment: On both moral and legal grounds, you should stop doing this immediately.

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question. If this did go to court, could they prosecute me with the other person's word alone? He was the only eyewitness around as we live in a pretty isolated area.

Comment: @duncan_evelyn if it's your word against his, you will likely not be convicted criminally (no proof beyond reasonable doubt), but you could quite likely be found civilly liable by a preponderance of the evidence (greater than 50% probability). This means that it is unlikely (but still possible) that you will go to prison, but quite likely that you will have to pay damages to the person you harassed and/or a fine to the government.

Comment: Or that person could snap one day and take you down.